# Android Studio FFMPEG "Protocol not found"

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am trying to run ffmpeg with android studio, but when I try the following code it shows this error message:

**E/mobile-ffmpeg: content://media/external/video/media/68: Protocol not found
E/mobile-ffmpeg: Did you mean file:content://media/external/video/media/68?**

This is my code:

```
inputVideo = "content://media/external/video/media/68"
videoTitle = "abc"
public void method(String inputVideo, String videoTitle) {
        String cmdLine = "-i " + inputVideo + " -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 file:" + videoTitle;
        FFmpeg.execute(cmdLine);
    }
```

I think that the 'content:' in **inputVideo** leads to the error but I don't know how I could fix it.
Already tried out the following:

- Add 'file:' in front of inputVideo and videoTitle
- Removing 'content://' from the string leads to not finding the file

Comment: I found a solution to my problem.
I had to get the real path from the Uri of the video and now it worked.

Comment: hello @Whitestripe7773 , what do you mean the real path? can you show me example id be glad of your support.

Comment: @Whitestripe7773 what exactly do you mean by real path? Was the input a file or just a path to the file?

Comment: I used this method to get the "realpath":      

    private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(context, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return result;
    }
I hope this will help someone :)